# BitmapSource to point to local file

Tags: c#, xaml, bitmap, windows-8

What's the best pattern to implement a local cache for a Metro Style App so that the images can be cached in the background while the app is being used on-line and to serve images when the App goes offline?

How do we set a BitmapSource to a local file upon discovering the lack of internet access? using new Uri(localpath, UriKind.Absolute) doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are the images already downloaded?  If so, are they in the "Local" folder?

If so, you can build a BitmapImage from the path like this

```
var m_Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/" + ImageFileName));
```

*EDIT*

If your file is stored in the package as a "never had access and can't download anything" standby, the Uri would be something like

```
var m_Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/" + FallBackImageFileName));
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this out - but what if I've put it in the package localfolder? yes I'm downloading them in advance and in the background

Comment: If you mean ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder as the package local folder, then the first Uri format is the one you want (new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/" + ImageFileName))

Comment: oh yes, that's the folder I want. I'll test it out and update.